# Skip Dataset entries in TFRecordDataset.map()

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

How do I skip entries in a TFRecord file when generating a TFRecordDataset?

Given a `TFRecord` file and `tf.contrib.data.TFRecordDataset` object, I create a new dataset by `map`ing over the protobuf definition. For example,

```
features = {'some_data': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)}

def parser(example_proto):
    e = tf.parse_single_example(example_proto, features)
    data = e['some_data']
    # ...do a bunch of stuff to data...
    return data

x = TFRecordDataset(filename)
x = x.map(parser)
x = x.cache(cache_filename)
x = x.repeat()
x = x.batch(batch_size)
```

This lets me read in the data and do some preprocessing, then cache the results and batch it up for my model.

My question is, what if I want to skip one of the TFRecord entries (e.g., if the data is invalid/bad)? For example, in `parser()`, maybe I could return `None`, or some sort of `tf.cond` to indicate an invalid entry, or trip some assertion.

Comment: How about using x.filter() or FilterDataset? https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/data/python/ops/dataset_ops.py#L1296

Comment: That is what I ended up using, `filter()`. I was worried I had to do it in `map()` due to my code architecture, but it turned out to be just fine with `filter` and appropriate predicate. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Summarizing the comment as an answer)

The [`filter()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#filter) method of `Dataset` could filter entries according to a predicate.

Comment: Could you give an example of the `filter()` syntax? I'm not sure how to define the predicate.

Comment: Here's an example: ```x = x.filter(lambda data: tf.greater(data, 0))```